# Place footer on bottom page while printing

Tags: html, css, printing

I'm trying for days to figure out how to solve this problem:

I have a report (full HTML5 + CSS3) with some pages. The report is divided by sections and each section has a header, a content and a footer. So, a section is basically composed like:

```
<section>
  <header></header>
  <div>CONTENT</div>
  <footer></footer>
</section>
```

The problem is that the footer comes right after content ends (see figure 1) when in **print** area (Ctrl + P), when it must stay at bottom of the section (see figure 2)...

I'm not a really front-end master and it has become a pain to achieve!
Can you help me with this?
Thanks!

**Figure 1:**

[image]

**Figure 2:**

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Go with something like this:

```
@media print {
    #footer {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        display: none;
    }

    @page: last {
        #footer {
            display: block;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: afaik it won't work. MDN: `You can only change the margins, orphans, widows, and page breaks of the document. Attempts to change any other CSS properties will be ignored.`

Answer (score 0):

you should use position absolute for the footer

```css
header{
  background-color:yellow;
  height: 50px;
}

footer{
  background-color:red;
position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <header>Header</header>
  <div>CONTENT</div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</section>
```

Comment: Will print out #footer at the bottom of every printed page. not only on the last one.

Comment: @AVI, thanks for the answer. Your solution works when content do not cause a page break... In my case, content often ocuppy 2 pages, so footer overlaps the text and appears only in first page...

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Add top margin to the footer, enough to cause it to break to the next page. 2 pages should be more than sufficient as given in the following example

Step2: Shift the footer back by giving the wrapper a negative margin and the footer position relative, and bottom: $height

Step3: Prevent page break of the next content because you already have forced the page break with the margin.

HTML:

```
<div class="article">
    <div class="content"><pre>
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
    </pre></div>
    <div class="footer">Stick to the bottom!</div>
</div>
<div class="article">
    <div class="content"><pre>
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT
    </pre></div>
    <div class="footer">Stick to the bottom!</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
$height: 50px;
$border: 1px;
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.article {
    page-break-after: avoid;
    >.footer {
        position: relative;
        height: $height;
        border: $border solid black;
    }
    pre {
        margin: 0;
    }
}
@page {
    size: a4;
}
@media print {
    .article {
        margin-bottom: calc(0px - $height - 4*$border);
    }
    .footer {
        bottom: calc($height + 4*$border); //border pixel
        margin-top: 594mm; //double of a4 page size
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a comment though, this will create a blank page in the last page however. I have not found a solution to avoid it.